# Partial segue to show settings view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

in the google maps app for ios.  When you select the settings button, it will show you a view of options such as "traffic", "public transit", etc.

My question is how this is done on ios.

I tried following [this](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/) tutorial but it says that it won't work on uinavigationviewcrollers.  I have seen this partial segue of the the view in apps that use a navigational controller.  How do they create that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a partial segue. It's not a segue at all, it use of containment view controllers.

Instead of a single view controller which transitions to a different view controller image one single master view controller. For simplicity, we'll say this view controller has two views (of the root), both of which cover the the whole screen. For this example let's think of them as "main" view and "menu" view.

Other than these two empty views, the view controller has no content. That's because this view controller does nothing other than manage other view controllers which get stuck into the two views. It will have a couple methods manage them, like `presentInMainView:(UIViewController *)viewcontroller` and `presentInMenuView:(UIViewController *)viewcontroller`

When the program starts running the master view controller will programmatically add the map to it's "main" view. The map view controller now cover the whole screen and looks and acts like it's the top level view controller, but it isn't. It's contained. At some point some taps the settings button and the map view controller will make a call to it's parent and say `presentInMenuView:...` and the master view controller will then load up a second view controller into the menu view. The menu view could even be located off the left side of the screen and the master view controller animates the menu view frame to side it right covering the whole screen. Assuming the menu view controller only has content which covers the left half of the screen you'll see the map view controller hiding behind it.

That really only scratches the surface, lots can be done with container view controllers. You could create a container which lets you brings up a dozen different views all populated with view different view controllers. You could size and arrange them on all over the screen and each child view controller could still only have to deal with it's own contents.

For more info there is [the Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) and the [WWDC 2011 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) where it was introduced (session 102)

Answer (score 0):

I used [**SWRevealViewController**](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) For similar type of sidebar animation.They given the good example of how to use **SWRevealViewController** also please try it once.